# Can this code be optimized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I am creating a page that allows users access to a certain section of my website if they click 8 out of 25 checkboxes in the right sequence.

First of all thanks to Reigel for the code, its way better than what I initialy started with.

My question is, can the javascript code I have be optimized. For instance, the clearforms function, or anything else. I am a noob, just started to work with javascript 3 days ago, so any advice is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">

 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="check_combination.php">
<table width="200" border="1" align="center">

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="6"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="7"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="8"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="9"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="10"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="11"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="12"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="13"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="14"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="15"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="17"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="18"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="19"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="20"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="21"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="22"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="23"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="24"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="25"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="23" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle" class="label"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="Test length" id="test" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" name="button" id="button2" value="Test hidden input value" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<input name="result" type="hidden" id="result" />

</form>

</body>
```

And the javascript:

```
function clearForms() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
       document.forms[i].reset();
    $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}


//initial checkCount of zero
var checkCount = 0;

//maximum number of allowed checked boxes
var maxChecks = 8;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]').click(function() {

        //update checkCount
        checkCount = $(':checked').length;

        if (checkCount >= maxChecks) {
            //alert('you may only choose up to ' + maxChecks + ' options');
            $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        if (this.checked) {
            $("td.label").append('<label>' + this.value + ' </label>');
        } else {
            $("td.label").find(':contains(' + this.value + ')').remove();
        }

        $('input[name="result"]').val($("td.label").text());

    });


    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert($(':checked').length)
    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        alert($('input[name="result"]').val());
    });

});
```

And this is the modified javascript per advice of Peter Ajtai (Thanks Again! To Peter, and Reigel the person who took the original code I had and rewrote it entirely to shorten it.)

```
function clearForms() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
       document.forms[i].reset();
    $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);

    }
}


//initial checkCount of zero
var checkCount = 0;

//maximum number of allowed checked boxes
var maxChecks = 8;

$(document).ready(function() {

clearForms();

var $nameCheckbox = $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]');

    $nameCheckbox.click(function() {

        //update checkCount
        checkCount = $('input:checked').length;

        if (checkCount >= maxChecks) {
            //alert('you may only choose up to ' + maxChecks + ' options');
            $nameCheckbox.not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $nameCheckbox.filter(':disabled').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        if (this.checked) {
            $("td.label").append('<label>' + this.value + ' </label>');
        } else {
            $("td.label").find(':contains(' + this.value + ')').remove();
        }

        $('input[name="result"]').val($("td.label").text());

    });


    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert($('input:checked').length)
    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        alert($('input[name="result"]').val());
    });

});
```

Comment: I edited this post to put code inline. James, the questions on this site are generally intended to be indexed by Google, such that people with similar issues can later find answers to their questions. Do not place links to temporary content. With only 3 reputation, it leads me to believe that it was a subtle advertisement.

Comment: @Stargazer: an advertisement for...jsfiddle? It's certainly nice to have the code available right in the question, but a jsfiddle link is a great convenience for people who want to tackle the question.

Comment: @Ian Henry, then those who wish to use jsfiddle can do so on their own. Links on reputable sites (such as this one) boost the page rank of the site being linked to. If James had more rep, I would be less suspicious. Either way, the content is temporary and the link would likely break in the future.

Comment: I apologize, I just learned of jsfiddle yesterday and thought it was really cool. I appreciate the advice. I am a newbie that has taken an interest in javascript, I did not intend on making it seem like advertising. Just thought it was a good way to show a live demonstration. I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: psst... You do realize that with a bit of CSS that **HTML** can also be simplified by *a lot*, eh

Comment: @Stargazer712, I spend far too many of my comments to questions *requesting* a live demo. And [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) are both useful services, and both of which I happily promote. I don't think there's been an editorial or edict issued, has there?

Comment: Yeah I figured it could, I was waiting to tackle the html once I got everything working. I used dreamweaver to slap this table together in order to get something visual to work with. If you have any suggestions on how to simplify the html, I would love to hear them, Im kinda new to html also.

Comment: @James it'd probably be **much** simpler if you didn't use Dreamweaver... =b

Comment: @David hehe, I know. Im getting there, pretty soon it will just be notepad.

Comment: @James, no worries I was only teasing =) That said, because I had a couple of minutes (and because it both **irks** and **pains** me to see tables in forms), here's a free comparison of your approach and mine, at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ileka3/). I've not added any JS, it's just a demo of the raw html approach. Wait... **Notepad** ? *Windows*..? =D I'm sorry, I'll stop that now. I'm not old enough to make it look good...

Comment: @David Thomas, as I said before, it was his low reputation that was the reason, not the mention of Js Fiddler. Prior to editing, it was nothing more than a link with the text "CLICK HERE TO SEE AN EXAMPLE ON JS FIDDLER" (or something to that effect).

Comment: @Stargazer, looking at the revision history, yeah, I see your point. And kudos to you for bringing the code on over =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that jumped out at me...

To speed things up use:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]')
```

instead of

```
$(':checkbox[name=checkbox]')
```

This is because the first version look for checkboxes only among the `input` elements, the second version looks for checkboxes over all elements.

Take a look at **[this speed comparison](http://jsperf.com/element-selector-test)** Nick Craver created to demonstrate the above for **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835486/a-way-to-chain-selectors-like-this-in-jquery-inputcheckednothidden/3835530#3835530)**.

Do this wherever possible, so use `$('input:checked')`.

Also, there are several jQuery objects you create multiple times.

For example you use, `$(':checkbox[name=checkbox]')` many times. Each time you recreate the same jQuery object, so do:

```
var $nameCheckbox = $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]');
$nameCheckbox.click(function() {
    ...
       $nameCheckbox.not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
       $nameCheckbox.filter(':disabled').attr('disabled', false);
    ...
```

Finally semantically, it makes more sense to remove the inline javascript, so replace:

```
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">
```

with

```
<body>
```

and put `clearForm()` inside the jQuery doc ready. The jQuery doc ready will fire before `window.onload` since `onload` has to wait for all images, etc to load. jQuery doc ready fires when the DOM is ready. You can also make use of `window.onunload`, but I don't quite understand why that's necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    clearForms();
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @James - You're welcome ;) I added one more thing about removing the inline JS and add `clearForms()` into doc ready which should fire a little before `onload` if you have any images and such on the page.

Comment: So for example would something like this be correct?   $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]').not('input:checked').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: @James - In that case,`$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]')` is a set of all `input` checkboxes with the name `checkbox`, so it is redundant to write `.not('input:checked')`. Instead write `.not(':checked')`......... In fact that's the example I wrote in my code above: `$nameCheckbox.not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);` which because of what `$nameCheckbox` is defined as is: `$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks for your help :) Thats exactly what I was wondering, whether or not 'input:checked' was necessary. Im going to implement the changes to the clearforms funtion as well. Can I post the code once I think it meets your advice and have you take one last look at it?

Comment: I think I have edited to meet your advice, I had to add to jfiddle because the code is too long for a message. here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/xSsrC/2/

Comment: @James - That looks pretty good. I notice you didn't include a [ `window.onunload = clearForms;` ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) - But I'm not sure what function that served any way.

Comment: I skimmed right over that section about window.onunload, was trying to modify quickly to get advice on mods. It seems to be clearing just fine though. When I first started, I had a problem with FireFox holding onto disabled checkboxes when reloading page, but it seems to be cleared up. Adding this code: $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);, to ClearForms() is the only thing that worked to clear disabled checkboxes onload, resetting the form wouldnt quite do the trick.